# best way to work with unknown size stream

Tags: c++, oop, stream

There is an unknown size stream (my class). Read() returns 0 when Stream ends. It's OK.
But a conceptual problem with CopyToEnd() appeares in this case.
CopyToEnd() reads some count of bytes from some position and copies them to the end of Stream. 
But how it can do this, if it doesn't know the stream size? 
May be it is a good idea to create a virtual abstract method SeekToEnd() and define it in the classes inherited by Stream? Or it is more reasonable to move method CopyToEnd() in the subclasses which know the size stream? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Consider a dynamic-growth algorithm for your read-buffer. Or a decision on how much data you'll process at a time, and read in partitions. Either way, this question is a little... nebulous.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you for comment. I am going to reconsider a behavior of CopyToEnd()

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can keep in the your class "after-end" linklist, where accumulate values from sequenced calls to CopyToEnd(). When you reach EOF from original file, don't return 0, but just start processing saved list. Return 0, when list ends.

This mechanism resolve many "edge situations" - for example, when you reading chunks from linklist (after end of real file), and same time - call CopyToEnd().